# Cannot chroot /mnt/sysimage After Putting New Image on HP Computer

Tags: linux, bash, centos, centos-7

I am using Clonezilla to put a new CentOS 7 image on our computers. Most of them are Lenovo desktops, and we have a few HP desktops that are all currently running the old image.

In order for the new image to work after Clonezilla restores it to the new image, we need to insert a USB with the CentOS 7 Rescue Disk and boot to it to run some commands, beginning with `chroot /mnt/sysimage`.

This works just fine on the Lenovo desktops, but when I run this command on the HP desktops, I get this error message:

`chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: No such file or directory`

Both the Lenovo and the HP machines have the same HD size (80 GB), and I am putting the exact same new image on both of them. I cannot for the life of me figure out why one is working and the other is not, and I don't want to dismantle the new image and start from scratch (we only have about 5 machines that are HP, the rest are Lenovo).

Could anyone provide some insight into why the chroot command does not work on the HP machines? Thanks.

Comment: Are one group of computers booting via EFI and the other ones via BIOS? This could lead to booting into different environments.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they are both booting via BIOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found that the HP machines (along with newer model Lenovos) were mounting the Linux partitions on `/dev/sdb` instead of `/dev/sda` when I inserted the CentOS 7 Rescue Disk.

This was because I had the Rescue Disk on a USB, so the system mounted the USB on `/dev/sda` instead of another partition.

To get around this, I downloaded the ISO for CentOS 7 and burned it to a DVD and booted to that.  I can now execute my `chroot` command without issue since the Linux partition is now on `/dev/sda`.

Thank you all for your suggestions and help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like /mnt/sysimage is not mounted as you expect. The command

```
mount | grep "/mnt/sysimage"
```

should tell you what is mounted at `/mnt/sysimage`. If there is no output, `/mnt/sysimage` is not mounted, in which case try mounting it manually. Use command:

```
cat /proc/partitions | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 5
```

to get a list of partitions. Then try

```
mount /dev/<partition_name> /mnt/sysimage
```

You might have to guess the correct partition name. It is not possible for us to tell from the information you supply. To try another partition unmount the former partition by

```
umount /mnt/sysimage
```

Comment: I got the list of partitions, but every time I try to run the `mount /dev/<partition_name> /mnt/sysimage` command, I get that the partition is write protected and read only.  I then try my `chroot /mnt/sysimage` command and get the exact same error as before.  I am fairly certain that it should be the `/dev/sda` that I am mounting, as my other commands need to run against that.

Comment: You might have a hardware related problem. Try `dmesg | grep sda` to find out more.

Comment: It can also happen that hard drive got detected as `sdb` in which case your usb drive is `sda` which probably has iso9660 file system (which is actually read-only)

Comment: Akash, that appears to be the case.  On the machines that are working, `/dev/sda` is the Linux partition, while on the machines that are NOT working, `/dev/sdb` is the Linux partition and `/dev/sda` appears to be the USB drive that I insert for the Rescue Disk.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is misleading and only means that either `/bin/bash` doesn't
exist (not your case); or that the dynamic loader used by `/bin/bash` doesn't
exist (probably your case);
or even that rsync was used to create the usr, lib and lib64 folders without the 
preserve links flag.

The most likely explanation is that the lib and/or lib64 folders are missing from
your chroot.

You should either copy the three usr, lib and lib64 folders while preserving links, or just `mount --bind` them to `/mnt/sysimage`.

Answer (score 0):

If it works on some machines but not others its possible the architectures are different.. I suspect one was setup 32 bit and the other 64 bit - need to ensure binaries and shared libraries exist for both architectures or the USB stick wont work for both..